# ML Kit face detection ML model size on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm successfully detecting faces with ML Kit on Android.

I configured ML Kit following the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces), including the fourth, optional but recommended:

> Configure your app to automatically download the ML model to the
>   device after your app is installed from the Play Store.

What I'm trying to discover now is the actual size of such ML model since it is downloaded automatically. Does anyone know where/how can I find that information? I want to know what's the total size a user will have to download when installing my app.

Answer (score 0):

The module downloaded is ~ 16MB for Face detection